# pykinect2 library works only with comtypes 1.1.4 which only works with python 2.7. Hence, not able to integrate media pipe, hand tracking with it

Tags: mediapipe, comtypes, kinect-v2, pykinect

COMtype compatibility issue :

As we know mediapipe works well with higher versions of python. i.e., 3.x and higher.
I am looking a for ways to implement features of mediapipe into pikinect2 for hand tracking and currently stuck at comtype errors.

Current suitable version of comtype for pykinect2 is v1.1.4

Kindly provide solutions to any one problem below.

1. An alternative solution to mediapipe at python version 2.7
2. Alternative way to make use of pykinect2 library for python 3.5 or higher versions without getting comtype errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This pull request from the pykinect2 repo shows you what code changes to make to the pykinect source code:

- https://github.com/Kinect/PyKinect2/pull/109

Here's the repo for the pull request:

- https://github.com/SujithChristopher/PyKinect2/tree/master

Honestly at this point it's more worth it to just download the python files from the pull request github and run them directly in your project's folder.

I've confirmed that this works on my python version of Python 3.8.18